# Displaying course data from Firebase for each user in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_course_fragment, null);

    textView=v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    final  DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query usersQuery = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("ANAND");


    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String course = ds.child("course").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, course);


                Query courseRef = rootRef.child("Course").orderByChild("name").equalTo(course);
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                            final String url = ds.child("url").getValue(String.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, name + " / " + url);
                            textView.setText(name);
                            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                    }
                };
                courseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

This code worked perfectly but when i reinstalled this again ,its not working according to my need.I actually needed to display particular course for each user what they registered to . But here only course for "ANAND" is displaying. How can i correct this Problem?

[image: My Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you start with `Query usersQuery = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("ANAND");` it makes sense that only the course for `ANAND` is displayed.

To show the same for all users, remove your condition:

```
Query usersQuery = rootRef.child("Users");
```

If the rest of your code works already, it will keep working with this change.

Comment: YES it worked .But now another issue arise. when i newly register new user then it shows correct course according to that user course. but when i loggwd in using another user then it shows what previously displayed

Comment: None of the code you shared does anything with Firebase Authentication, so I have no idea how to interpret this new problem. I'd recommend spending some time isolating that problem (see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for great hints on that), and then post it in a new question.